# SharpDX: How use `TryGetFontTable` function with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sharpdx

I want to get font 'CMAP' table, How use `TryGetFontTable` function with C#?

The first parameter is `int openTypeTableTag`, how I convert 'CMAP' to int?

The documentation states:

> The four-character tag of a OpenType font table to find. Use the
>   DWRITE_MAKE_OPENTYPE_TAG macro to create it as an UINT32. Unlike GDI,
>   it does not support the special TTCF and null tags to access the whole
>   font.

How I do that with C#?

The next parameter is `out DataPointer tableData`, how I parse the data as map table to use like dictnery?

Comment: Documentation is here: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct2D1/DirectWrite/FontFace.cs#L131
If you need help, please provide more details.

Comment: @DogeAmazed I provided more details

Comment: Read the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368103(v=vs.85).aspx and just convert it to C#? There is an example and also what the macro is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the macro, use [`DWRITE_FONT_FEATURE_TAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368069(v=vs.85).aspx) enumeration.

`DWRITE_FONT_FEATURE_TAG_GLYPH_COMPOSITION_DECOMPOSITION` matches the table you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, how I parse the data as map table to use like dictnery?